# What caused the redirection loop with this nginx configuration file?

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, dns

This is for a wordpress blog, with http and https access. We dont need to redirect http traffic to https. In addition, I want to access it either by `http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com`, `https://example.com`, or `https://www.example.com`

There are several problems caused by the following configuration.

1. `http://www.example.com/fold1/readme.php` will be redirected to `https://fold1/readme.php`
2. `https://example.com/fold1/readme.php` will be redirected to `https://fold1/readme.php`
3. > `'https://www.example.com/fold1/readme.php'` was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script `'http://www.example.com/fold1/js/user-profile.min.js?ver=4.3'`. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
   >
   > `readme.php:1` Mixed Content: The page at `'https://www.example.com/fold1/readme.php'` was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script `'http://www.example.com/fold1/js/language-chooser.min.js?ver=4.3'`. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        server_name example.com www.example.com *.example.com; 
#        return  301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
#}
#
#server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        keepalive_timeout   70;

        #ssl on; 
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/example.com-unified.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/example.com.key;

        server_name  example.com www.example.com *.example.com;
        server_name_in_redirect off;

        charset utf-8;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html/example.com;

        access_log /home/wwwlogs/example.com.access.log;
        error_log /home/wwwlogs/example.com.error.log;

       #if ($http_host != "www.example.com") {
       #          rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
       #}

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        #fastcgi_cache start
        set $skip_cache 0;

        # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
        if ($request_method = POST) {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }   
        if ($query_string != "") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }   

        # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
        if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }   

        # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
        if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        location / {
            # try files in the specified order
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args /index.html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.(php|php5)?$ {
        #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
            ModSecurityEnabled on;  
            ModSecurityConfig modsecurity.conf;

            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;  #DEBUG
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            # use upstream hhvm/php
            fastcgi_pass php;
            fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD; # Only GET and HEAD methods apply
            fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache; #apply the "$skip_cache" variable
            fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

            fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 60m;

            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            # send bad requests to 404
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        }


        location ~ /purge(/.*) {
            fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
        }   

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
               deny all;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|flv|ico)$ {
            access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
        }

        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
                expires 7d;
                }

        location = /robots.txt {
            access_log off; log_not_found off; 
            }

        # Make sure files with the following extensions do not get loaded by nginx because nginx would display the source code, and these files can contain PASSWORDS!
        #
        location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ /\. { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }


        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        sysguard on;
        sysguard_load load=1.8 action=/loadlimit;
        sysguard_mem swapratio=90% action=/swaplimit;

        location /loadlimit {
            return 503;
            }

        location /swaplimit {
            return 503;
            }

        if ( $query_string ~* ".*[\;'\<\>].*" ){
                return 404;
        }

}
```

EDIT:

commented out following lines:

```
       #if ($http_host != "www.example.com") {
       #          rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
       #}
```

Comment: Have you tried server_name_in_redirect off; to server_name_in_redirect on;

Comment: tried to turn server_name_in_redirect on, but these problems still exist.

Comment: May have something to do with the ssl. Make sure you have a valid ssl certificate on the server in the correct directory.

Comment: The ssl key should be fine, since phpmyadmin server works all right.

Comment: If you don't want redirect, you should remove this part:

if ($http_host != "www.example.com") {
                 rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
}

It's not correct anyway. Judging by the last versions documentation, there is no $http_host variable, there is $host. So your rule will always trigger.

Comment: Yes. I have commented out this part. But these problems mentioned in the post still exists. Any further comments?

Comment: To resolve your 3rd issue, change the paths in your readme.php and other files to use paths such as `//www.example.com/fold1/js/user-profile.min.js?ver=4.3` instead of `http://www.example.com/fold1/js/user-profile.min.js?ver=4.3`. With this, it will correctly request HTTP or SSL based on how the main file was requested. Personally, I will reactivate the code to always redirect to SSL.